# Solving Normal Distribution Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The mean length of 600 stainless steel sticks is 181mm and the standard deviation is 60mm.Assuming that the length is normally distributed,

1) find the probability that a randomly chosen stick is between 150 and 190mm in length.

2)Given that the length of a particular stick is more than 195mm, find the conditional probability that is actual length exceeds 210mm.

I already solve part (1). For part 2 i dont know. Could someone help me out

Comment: [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem)?

Comment: not sure. It says conditional probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event "greater than $195$" and let $B$ be the event "greater than $210$."  We want $\Pr(B|A)$. By a standard formula,
$$\Pr(B|A)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A)}.$$

Note that $\Pr(B\cap A)$ is just $\Pr(B)$. If you solved the first problem then you know how to find $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$.

**Remark:** Intuitively, $\Pr(A)$ is the area under a certain "tail" of the normal. Our answer $\dfrac{\Pr(B)}{\Pr(A)}$ is just the ratio of the area past $210$ to the area past $195$.

Comment: how about Pr(A)??

Comment: So this is my steps : P(X>210|X>195)= P(Z>0.483|Z>0.233)=$$\frac{P(Z>0.483)}{P(Z>0.233)}$$.And i got the answer 0.7712. Is my answer right??

Comment: $\Pr(A)$ is the probability of being more than $14$ above the mean, so it is $\Pr(Z\gt 14/60$. Now use normal tables or software.

Comment: yeah andre i got my Pr(A) as above i posted.Just want to clarify with you tht is my working above is correct

Comment: Yes, the method is right, and a glance at a normal table shows that your numbers look OK.

Comment: Ok Sir thank you very much for your help and effort. You really help me out well!!! Thanks again